# Lightbox2 doesn't load all images in Fotorama slider

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, lightbox2, fotorama

I have fotorama slider (in wordpress page) that open lightbox2 (v2.7.1) on main image click. The problem is that lightbox2 is showing only up to 3 images in popup....even if in fotorama slider there are more images.

Seems like lightbox2 is not showing all images, because all images is not showing in fotorama thumbnails (they are hidden). But how to solve this problem?

Code of Fotorama:

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('galerija_jedi');
if( $images ): ?>
    <div class="fotorama2" 
    id = "fotorama_jedi"
    data-nav="thumbs"
    data-maxheight="430px"
    data-loop="true"
    data-autoplay="true"
    data-keyboard="true"
    data-thumbfit="cover"
    data-thumbheight="80px"
    data-thumbwidth="80px"
    data-arrows="false"
    data-allowfullscreen="false"
    data-thumbmargin="10"
    data-shadows="false"
    data-arrows="false"
     data-click="false"
     data-swipe="false"
    >
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                    <div data-img="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" >
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="lightbox[group]" data-title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>">                     
                        </a>
                    </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The slider must be used to navigate the images *in* Fotorama, it is not expected you change this behavior. Also still don't catch what you want to accomplish: it is possible to zoom the current selected photo (and sometime desiderable) but why are you tinkering with the slider?

You should also be aware that Fotorama modifies the DOM and only preload the previous and next image, so if you are on the second photo you will likely zoom only the previous, current and next slide.

Comment: Im looking for increase preload fotorama images. I need that it preload all images, so lightbox can read them properly